# Why exactly was this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, off-topic, on-hold

A couple of days ago, I asked this question
[Low-pass filter in MATLAB returning NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935871/cant-apply-filter-in-matlab/)

It was about applying a low-pass filter in Matlab. I included in the question what I wanted to do, references to the pages I have been googling up to try to find the solution, and why this solution doesn't work for me. I had code examples I and thought I explained the problem short and concise while including all relevant information.

I received a downvote however, and when I questioned the downvote, the question was put on hold. If I did something wrong, I want to know what it was, so that I can do better next time. I don't see what I did wrong.

It was flagged as "Off topic". When I go to the help center and read exactly what Off topic means, it is explained as "This question does not appear to be about programming". I'm not really sure how my question was not about programming. The example code is four lines of code that will run if you have the specified sound file. Why is it not "Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable"?

Comment: Read the *entire* close reason.  Don't stop at the word "offtopic".

Comment: I read more than "offtopic" from the close reason. It said I didn't include a "Minimal example". I looked up what a minimal example is and as my above post indicated, I have understood that it means "Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable".

Comment: @user1661303 So you skipped over the part in **bold**, the part that might be important?  `"it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem."`

Comment: @user1661303 Your example is not complete because nobody else has `funky.wav`.  It's best if you can include data in the question itself (rather than a link) that shows the behavior.  Note that the process of producing such an example often leads you to the solution, in which case you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Servy What questions were I asked that I didn't answer? Only one person asked me questions about the value of three variables and I answered them all with  very specific numerical values. Are looking at the same question?

Comment: @Matthew-Lundberg funky.wav is just a sound file. It works the same with all sound files. It's taken from an example on a web page and he doesnt provide the sound file either. I am doing it on a copyrighted song that I have asked permission to manipulate locally, but I'm not comfortable uploading it to the open internet. How can I possibly upload a sound file with millions of samples to a Stackoverflow post without including a link? I have specified the sampling rate of the song and that it is in stereo. It should be enough.

Comment: @user1661303 That doesn't matter.  The lack of any data makes your code incomplete.  You should not upload the file; you should present the data in a format that can be pasted into Matlab along with the code.  It should not take more than a handful of samples to demonstrate the problem (unless your filter length is in the millions, something that I highly doubt).

Comment: @Servy What information is needed to diagnose the problem that I haven't already given? I have specified the sampling rate, type of file and whether the song is in mono or stereo . The problem is perfectly reproducible. Do you seriously expect me to include every single sample in a 3 minutes song?

Comment: @user1661303 I don't know; it's beyond my area of expertise.  I'm simply telling you why your question was closed; 5 people felt that it was lacking sufficient information.

Comment: @Matthew-Lundberg It's audio sampled with 44100 samples/s. Even displaying one tenth of a second would require 4410 samples. It would be impossible to hear if the filter had worked so I dont think including samples of the audio file would help verify if the solution had worked.

Comment: @user1661303 From your question:  "I get no error, but all the values in the output of the filter is NaN, Why is that? The song is in stereo, could that be it?"  You do not need thousands of samples to see if the values are `NaN`.  A dozen or so will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been a lot of years since my Signal Processing classes, and I haven't touched Matlab in almost that long, so I'm going to avoid a technical analysis of the issue and try to focus on some aspects of the question that are jumping out at me.

---

### Close Reason

First the close reason does give a general idea of what is wrong.

> "This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself."

The close voters are saying your post is missing info to properly diagnose the problem.  It is impossible to say exactly what is missing without asking the specific close votes, but I have some thoughts:

You received a follow up comment asking for your value for `f` (the frequency) about 30 minutes after you posted the question and it took you 2 days to respond.  That is great that you responded, but I think that bit of information are vital to diagnosing the problem.  And while I can't see the details of when the close votes came in (except the last one), I would bet heavily that you had at least one and probably 2 or 3 votes in those couple of days after your question but before you responded.

Next you never edited those values into the question, so someone who is reading the question while reviewing the close votes might not see the comment and vote to close for the same reason.

In the comments here, you've suggested this is a problem with any audio file, not just the one your tried, so say that.  Unless you are explicit, people are going to guess that it might be a localized issue with a specific audio track or file, or aren't going to know for sure.

---

### Title

Your title is a problem

> Can't apply filter in Matlab

That is not a good title.  The title is suppose to be specific and describe the problem.  This is neither specific nor does it really describe your problem.  It is just a statement "I can't do something".  A title is the first view of your post someone gets and a bad title can bias someone against your question before they even read it (assuming they even bother to read it).

I am not great with titles, so someone might have a better suggestion but I think something like

> Low pass filter in Matlab returning NaN values

would attract more positive attention as it really describes your problem.

---

### Excess noise and "other" question

Your post has some noisy bits.  Your first sentence seems to be completely irrelavant to the problem at hand.  That's great that you've been able to load audio files and synthesis them, but are they really related to your problem?

Also, "thanks in advance" is also noisy.  You don't need to thank us, so don't add that.

At the end of the post, you kind of slip in another question

> I also want to apply a sweeping filter, like a bandpass that goes from 200 Hz to 2000 Hz. Is there any way to make this 'smooth' mathematically, without taking a small window of 500 ms, apply one bandpass filter, move up a little bit, and take another bandpass filter with slightly increased frequency?

This looks to be related, but it certainly isn't part of the same issue, so why add it?  The guidelines strongly recommend one question per post, so this other question is just distracting and only adds noise to the post.  Remove it, worry about your current problem, then when that is solved, then try to solve this issue and ask a separate question about that if you need help.

---

### To Wrap Up (and tl;dr;)

I am not a Matlab expert, so take this with a grain of salt, but your post doesn't look too bad.  It looks like your question is just suffering from a few minor issues

- You failed to edit missing information into the post (you instead left the response in a comment)
- You failed to mention if this issue was localized to specific audio files or if you are having the same problem on any audio file
- Your title was poor
- Your question had a lot of excess noise

However, the fact that you had multiple minor problems and a late response to the clarification comment kind of all clumped together and resulted in closure.

It's unfortunate but once your question starts down the path to get closed, it can sometimes be difficult to stop if your post is not a high quality one.  Someone reviewing might see the close reason and the issues and say "close it, this post doesn't deserve to stay open" so it is important to try to make your question as good as possible as soon as possible.

This illustrates one of the most important factors in asking questions and getting good answers... **stick around**.  Don't ask a question and not check back for a couple of days.  Be available for the first 15-30 minutes and then check back every few hours and make sure no one has provided any feedback.  And if they do, try to provide a response as quickly as you can, whether or not you think it is relavent.

Comment: Very nicely put. Having a relevant title and sticking around to answer questions and clarify the issue are indeed two of the most vital aspects to a specific problem question.

Comment: The above post is awesome. I understand it much better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not complete because nobody else has `funky.wav`. It's best if you can include data in the question itself (rather than a link) that shows the behavior. Note that the process of producing such an example often leads you to the solution, in which case you can answer your own question.

It should not take more than a handful of samples to demonstrate the problem.  The sample data should be included in the question itself, in a format that can be pasted into Matlab.

Edit your question to include such data, and it will likely be reopened (and perhaps even the downvote retracted).

Comment: Even though I don't think posting the sound file should be necessary, since everybody has sound files on their computer, for copyright reasons I have given above, and the fact that it gives the same behaviour for all sound files, I realise it may help open the question and is a lot more helpful than the above "Just read the close reason". I will try to see if I can synthesise some sound and edit the question to include it in a short way. I didn't think it was necessary, but you have helped me see that other's may think it was. Thanks!